# How to get the value from a directive in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive for my app in Angular and need to pass value to my controller

I have something like

```
controllers.directive('checkBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            checkAll: '=',
        },
        template: '<input check-all="checkAll" type="checkbox" ng-model="check"/>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('checkAll', function(newVal){
                scope.check = newVal;
            })
        }
    }
})

app.controller('test', function(){
    $scope.submit=function(){
    //not sure how to get the checkbox value as $scope.check is undefined....        
    }
})
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="test">
 <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <check-box></check-box>{{item.name}}
 </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">submit</button
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly this directive should do? I'd like to help but I need more information about the expected behavior.

Comment: the directive can check if the 'check All' checkbox is checked and will check all checkboxes.

Comment: I don't see you using `checkAll` any where. You seem to be setting `<input check-all="checkAll" ` but that won't use the `checkAll` scope variable, merely use it as a string value for `check-all` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You are using two way binding using `=` for `checkAll`.

```
scope: {
    checkAll: '=',
}
```

This is the way you do it. Basically, your directive will have a `check-all` attributed and whatever `$scope` variable you pass to it from the controller's view, you can modify that variable inside the directive and the value will be reflected back in the controller.

So for example, lets say your controller has a scope variable called `testValue`. Then you can use it in markup like so:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <check-box check-all="testValue"></check-box>{{item.name}}
</div>
```

And now whatever the directive does to `checkAll` in the directive's link function will be reflected in your controller's `$scope.testValue`.

So if you want some other variable in your controller to get a different value, just add another attribute for your directive like `checkAll` and it should do the job.

Hope that helps.

### UPDATED:

I read your code properly and I think I know what you need. Let me try to churn it out for you.

```
controllers.directive('checkBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            checkAll: '='
        },
        template: '<input check-all="checkAll" type="checkbox" ng-model="ngModel"/>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('checkAll', function(newVal){
                scope.check = newVal;
            })
        }
    }
})

app.controller('test', function(){
    $scope.submit=function(){
      console.log($scope.checkboxVariable);
      // or use $http service to send the value
    }
})
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="test">
  <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <check-box ng-model="checkboxVariable"></check-box>{{item.name}}
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">submit</button
</div>
```

Let me explain this a bit.

I think what you want is that your directive replaces with a checkbox input element. And when it is checked, then something in the scope must get set. The directive cannot set anything unless it is permitted to set a value on controller's scope. This you can achieve by using double binding using `=` setting. So we defined a new scope attribute called `ngModel` with double binding. And in the markup, we pass it a scope variable called `check`. Now when the input checkbox is checked/unchecked, the directive's scope gets its value on its own scope's `ngModel` variable. And since `ngModel` has double binding on it, it get's reflected in the controller's `check` variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am still not sure about how to access the checked boxes under my submit function. would you please put some codes inside the function? thanks. +!

Comment: Please check the answer again. Check `ng-model` in the HTML and your `submit()` function.